# How to get response of a service in an array for use, in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I had declare an array.at .ts file:

```
responsearray:any=[];
```

Inside constructor:

```
constructor(private _dataService: UserService, private _ngZone: NgZone) {
 this.responsearray = this.getmarkers(id);
 this.moveMarker(this.responsearray);
}
```

I want to pass updated value of response array in movemarker function and it also updated inside function getmarkers, but updated values not reflected above:

```
getmarkers(id) {

this._dataService
    .GetMarker(id)
    .subscribe(res => {
            this.responseformate = Object.assign({}, res);
            this.responsearray = this.responseformate.responsepacket;

        },
        error => console.log(error),
        () => {
            return (this.responsearray);
        })
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue :**

You are returning value from async call , if you want to do it that way then you have to return observables and then have to subscribe the event , by simply returning value you will not get the expected result it will return the observable.

**Simple way to achieve output is :**

```
constructor(private _dataService: UserService, private _ngZone: NgZone) {
 this.getmarkers(id);
}

getmarkers(id) {
    this._dataService
    .GetMarker(id)
    .subscribe(res => {
            this.responseformate = Object.assign({}, res);
            this.responsearray = this.responseformate.responsepacket;
            this.moveMarker(this.responsearray);
        },
        error => console.log(error));
}
```

**Another way :**

```
constructor(private _dataService: UserService, private _ngZone: NgZone) {
    this.getmarkers(id).subscribe(() => { 
        this.moveMarker(this.responsearray);
    });
}

getmarkers(id):Observable {
    return this._dataService
    .GetMarker(id)
    .map(res => {
            this.responseformate = Object.assign({}, res);
            this.responsearray = this.responseformate.responsepacket;
        },
        error => console.log(error));
}
```

Comment: by simply returning value you will not get the expected result it will return the observable.
-> How can i get value from returned observable.

Comment: then you have to subscribe again and return observable from getmarkers function. I have also updated the answer please try that out.